# picking out elements based on complement of indices in Python pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe out of which I pick two subset dfs, `df_a` and `df_b`. For example in `iris` dataset:

```
df_a = iris[iris.Name == "Iris-setosa"]
df_b = iris[iris.Name == "Iris-virginica"]
```

What's the best way to get all elements of `iris` that are neither in `df_a` nor in `df_b`? I prefer not to refer to the original conditions that defined `df_a` and `df_b`.  I just assume that `df_a` and `df_b` are subsets of `iris`, so I'd like to pull out elements from `iris` based on the indices of `df_a` and `df_b`.  Basically, assume that:

```
df_a = get_a_subset(iris)
df_b = get_b_subset(iris)
# retrieve the subset of iris that 
# has all elements not in df_a or in df_b
# ...
```

**EDIT:** here is a solution that seems inefficient and inelegant and I'm sure pandas has a better way:

```
# get subset of iris that is not in a nor in b
df_rest = iris[map(lambda x: (x not in df_a.index) & (x not in df_b.index), iris.index)]
```

And a second one:

```
df_rest = iris.ix[iris.index - df_a.index - df_b.index]
```

how can this be done most efficiently/elegantly in pandas? thanks.

Comment: Check out this question, which may give you some good answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134635/slice-pandas-dataframe-by-labels-that-are-not-in-a-list

Comment: what about `pandas.Index.difference` ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This seems a bit faster than your second solution.  There's a bit more overhead when indexing with `.ix`:

```
df[~df.index.isin(df_a.index+df_b.index)]
```