# Slice Pandas dataframe by index values that are (not) in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe, `df`.

I want to select all indices in `df` that are **not** in a list, `blacklist.`

Now, I use list comprehension to create the desired labels to slice.

```
ix=[i for i in df.index if i not in blacklist]  
df_select=df.loc[ix]
```

Works fine, but may be clumsy if I need to do this often.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropping rows from dataframe based on a "not in" condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965295/dropping-rows-from-dataframe-based-on-a-not-in-condition)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) on the index and invert the boolean index to perform label selection:

```
In [239]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[239]:
          a
0 -0.548275
1 -0.411741
2 -1.187369
3  1.028967
4 -2.755030
In [240]:

t = [2,4]
df.loc[~df.index.isin(t)]
Out[240]:
          a
0 -0.548275
1 -0.411741
3  1.028967
```

Answer (score 25):

You could use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to create the difference between your original indices and those that you want to remove:

```
df.loc[set(df.index) - set(blacklist)]
```

It has the advantage of being parsimonious, as well as being easier to read than a list comprehension.

Answer (score 6):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[5,6,7,8], index=[1,2,3,4], columns=['D',])
blacklist = [2,3]

df.drop(blacklist,0)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please include a brief description of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This, in my opinion, is a lot prettier/more elegant than doing `df.loc[~df.index.isin(blacklist)]`. However, it is less interpretable, since usually people only use `drop` to remove columns (so `axis=1`).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to ASGM; I found that I needed to turn the set into a list to make it work with a MultiIndex:

```
mi1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1), ("b", 2)])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={"aaa":[1,2,3,4]}, index=mi1)
setValid = set(df1.index) - set([("a", 2)])
df1.loc[list(setValid)] # works
df1.loc[setValid] # fails
```

(sorry can't comment, insufficient rep)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a way to select all rows that are outside a condition you can use `np.invert()` given that the condition returns an array of booleans.

```
df.loc[np.invert(({condition 1}) & (condition 2))]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use difference() to obtain the difference between your original indices and those that you want to exclude:

```
df.loc[df.index.difference(blacklist), :]
```

It has the advantage of being easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[5,6,7,8], index=[1,2,3,4], columns=['D',])
blacklist = [2,3]
#your current way ...
ix=[i for i in df.index if i not in blacklist]  
df_select=df.loc[ix]

# use a mask
mask = [True if x else False for x in df.index if x not in blacklist]
df.loc[mask]
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-label
actually, loc and iloc both take a boolean array, in this case the `mask`. from now on you can reuse this mask and should be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Inside [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) you can access your variable `blacklist` using `@`:

```
df.query('index != @blacklist')

# Or alternatively:
df.query('index not in @blacklist')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `np.setdiff1d` function which finds the set difference of two arrays.

```
index = np.array(blacklist)
not_index = np.setdiff1d(df.index.to_numpy(), index)
df.iloc[not_index]
```