# How to filter data frame based on index values in a separate list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list (list1) that looks like this:

```
  ['loc1','loc3','loc6'.....]
```

I also have a data frame (df1) that looks like this:

```
        Values    Proportion
loc1    200          10
loc2    50           20
loc3    100          30
loc4    60           45
loc5    70           12
loc6    80           11
loc7    10           10
....
```

I want to remove the rows where my index in the data frame matches values in the list. The resultant output file:

```
        Values    Proportion
loc2    50           20
loc4    60           45
loc5    70           12
loc7    10           10
....
```

My solution would be (but doesn't work).

```
reduced_file = set(df1.index) - list1
```

Comment: You can use `df.loc(list1)` for that.

Comment: this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Oh, sorry, square brackets instead of those: `df.loc[list1]`. That should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slice Pandas dataframe by labels that are not in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134635/slice-pandas-dataframe-by-labels-that-are-not-in-a-list)

Answer (score 6):

Try it like this:

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(list1)]
```

Comment: Or 
    `df= df[~df.index.isin(list1)]`

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut I was referring to the part with filtering, but if assignment would matter I guess it would be `reduced_file = df.loc[~df.index.isin(list1)]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.Index.difference` to create a new index that is the set difference between the existing index and the list of indices to remove.

```
df.loc[df.index.difference(list1)]

      Values  Proportion
loc2      50          20
loc4      60          45
loc5      70          12
loc7      10          10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `reindex`

```
df.reindex([x for x in df.index if x not in  ['loc1','loc3','loc6']])
Out[946]: 
      Values  Proportion
loc2      50          20
loc4      60          45
loc5      70          12
loc7      10          10
```

Comment: I like reindex too (-:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
All_index = list(df1.index.values)
Desired_list=[item for item in All_index if item not in list1]
df_filter=df1.filter(items=Desired_list, axis=0)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76260749/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).