# pandas multi-index slicing by index values that are not in a list

Tags: python, pandas

A similar question to [Slice Pandas dataframe by index values that are (not) in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134635/slice-pandas-dataframe-by-index-values-that-are-not-in-a-list), in the particular case of [multi index slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html#pandas-indexslice).

Sample data copied from `help(df.loc)`:

```
import pandas
tuples = [
   ('cobra', 'mark i'), ('cobra', 'mark ii'),
   ('sidewinder', 'mark i'), ('sidewinder', 'mark ii'),
   ('viper', 'mark ii'), ('viper', 'mark iii')
]
index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
values = [[12, 2], [0, 4], [10, 20],
        [1, 4], [7, 1], [16, 36]]
df = pandas.DataFrame(values, columns=['max_speed', 'shield'], index=index)
```

Multi index slicing can be used to select all rows that contain "mark i" as their second index:

```
idx = pandas.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, "mark i"],:]
```

I would like to inverse the selection. The result should contain all rows that do not contain "mark i" as their second index.

Answer (score 3):

An *easy* method would be to use `isin`:

```py
df.loc[~df.index.isin(["mark ii"], level=1)]

                     max_speed  shield
cobra      mark i           12       2
sidewinder mark i           10      20
viper      mark iii         16      36
```

`pandas index.isin` allows checks on a particular level, in this case, we are interested in the second level (level = 1)