# how to find the complement of two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

given two large dataframes, is there any concise and efficient code (avoid using any `for loop` directly) that allow me to obtain the complement of these two dataframes?

the most straight forward way to me is to compute `union-intersection` as shown in the naive example below, but I do not know how to implement this in an elegant languages of `pandas` or `np`

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K0', 'K1', 'K2'],
                     'key2': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1'],
                   'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})     
df2= pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K1', 'K1', 'K2'],
                      'key2': ['K0', 'K0', 'K0', 'K0'],
                      'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                      'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})        
intersection= pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner',on=['key1', 'key2'])
union=pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer',on=['key1', 'key2'])       


complement=union-intersection
```

thanks for any comments and answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [picking out elements based on complement of indices in Python pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986510/picking-out-elements-based-on-complement-of-indices-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @Mathias711, thanks. To apply their solution, I need to find the index of the `intersection` in the `union`. then I can apply their method to exclude previously obtained index

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K0', 'K1', 'K2'],
                     'key2': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1'],
                   'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})     
df2= pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K1', 'K1', 'K2'],
                      'key2': ['K0', 'K0', 'K0', 'K0'],
                      'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                      'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})        
intersection  = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner',on=['key1', 'key2'])
union         = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer',on=['key1', 'key2'])
```

print union

```
     A    B key1 key2    C    D
0   A0   B0   K0   K0   C0   D0
1   A1   B1   K0   K1  NaN  NaN
2   A2   B2   K1   K0   C1   D1
3   A2   B2   K1   K0   C2   D2
4   A3   B3   K2   K1  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN   K2   K0   C3   D3
```

print intersection

```
    A   B key1 key2   C   D
0  A0  B0   K0   K0  C0  D0
1  A2  B2   K1   K0  C1  D1
2  A2  B2   K1   K0  C2  D2
```

union-intersection try this:

```
union[union.isnull().any(axis=1)]

     A    B key1 key2    C    D
1   A1   B1   K0   K1  NaN  NaN
4   A3   B3   K2   K1  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN   K2   K0   C3   D3
```

Comment: thanks a lot, and I do not have enough reputation the upvote you though

Comment: I have thumbed you up!